# Which implementation is more efficient for Search Engine database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a search engine (school project). I have a problem to implement my database. 
In current structure, i have a table for Words (id, word, id of the web page, ...) and a table for Webpages (id, web page, ...). This way i am getting Words table filled with many duplicated entities (in case same word appears in three web pages, i will get 3 entries in Words table.

Ideally i would like to have an entity for a word (in Words table) that is coupled with an array of web pages.

Should i implement a different structure: first table for Words (id, word), second table for Webpages(id, web page)  and a third table for the combination Word_At_Webpage (word id, web page id)?

Is there a better way to implement the database?

Thank you!

Comment: I would not create a table for each word. It's cool to optimize for Size, Reads, Writes, or what-have-you... but it's not cool to create a schema that completely defies the entire point of an RDBMS. I like the second schema from a logic point of view. You have webpages, you have words, and you have a relationship between the two... feels like the beginnings of a Graph Schema. But I also like the first schema as it will be quicker for read/write which is probably more appropriate for a web search app.

Comment: @JNevill What would you choose? The first solution doesn't feel right...

Comment: Personally, because the primary story of search engine is the ability to search, I would optimize for read, so the first schema with two tables would win. When it comes to read, denormalization wins.

Comment: You should absolutely implement your "different structure", it will save you a lot of trouble during implementation and running/maintaining your application. Btw it is a form of database-normalization ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)).